# Angular.js binding checkbox value to mySQL bit

Tags: mysql, angularjs, data-binding

I am working on setting up an application using an Angular, Express, Node, mySQL stack and I am having an issue binding the value of a checkbox. mySQL stores boolean values as a bit so the json response is coming back with { done: 1 }, however angular seems to only accept boolean or string values to bind to true/false.

I have the following model (I have also tried defining done as DataTypes.BOOLEAN to no avail):

```
var Todo = sequelize.define('todos', {
    text: DataTypes.STRING,
    done: DataTypes.INTEGER
  })
```

my code is setting the values for that model to this:

```
{"todos":[
    {"id":1,"text":"add my first todo","done":1},
    {"id":2,"text":"Get the done toggle working","done":0}
]}
```

Lastly in my view I have this code (I am using jade):

```
li(ng-repeat="todo in todos")
    input(type="checkbox", ng-model='todo.done') 
    {{todo.text}}
```

However the checkbox is not being checked. I have tried adding ng-true-value but since it only accept string values I can't set true to an integer.

How can I get angular to work with the bit value stored by the database?

**Update**: I have updated my node server to convert the value of done into a boolean which is working good. Is that the recommended solution or is there a better way to accomplish this? (this solution feels a bit hacky to me and I feel like there must be a built in way to accomplish this without rewriting the server response in node)

```
todos.retrieveAll(function(todos) {
    if(todos) {
        todos.forEach(function(todo) {
            todo.done = Boolean(todo.done);
        });
        res.json({
            todos: todos
        });
    } else {
        res.send(401, "No todos found");
    }
}, function(err) {
    res.send(501, "Error retrieveing todos. Message: " + err);
    console.log("Error: " + err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="mymodel.myvalue" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" value="myvalue">
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.com. If you want to answer the question then try to explain with proper code and explanation. see [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use ng-true-value and ng-false-value, I had an issue because my values were being sent as json_encoded array which meant that I had to include the quotes to make it compare correctly.

Script:

```
// this is the model object that is bound to by the checkbox (amongst other things) 
// and in my case is "1" for true "0" for false - note this is an array as passed back from my data source so I am using [0] in the HTML ng-model - if you have a straight object then you would bind to myScopeBoundVar and it would be defines as something like {"active":1} or in my case the 1 would be a string.

myScopeBoundVar=[{"active":"1", "surname" : "Smith"}];
```

HTML

```
<input value="check" ng-model="myScopeBoundVar[0].active" ng-true-value="'1'" ng-false-value="'0'" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched">
```